# What is the lifetime and scope of dynamically allocated memory using new operator inside a class method?

Tags: c++, oop, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a class with a method allocating some memory using new operator, can other members of class can excess that memory? How about outside the class?

Comment: Depends what you do with the return value of `new`. If you do nothing with it, and just write `int myfunction() { new int; return 12 }` then *nothing* can access the memory, not even the function that allocated it, and you have a memory leak. Of course that would be absurd, but there's more than one different non-absurd thing you might have done, with different results.

Comment: It doesnt matter where/when you new it, the lifetime (of the memory) ends when you delete it (or when you call the dtor, the lifetime of the object ends).

Answer (score 8):

In general, dynamically allocated memory will "live" as long as you don't explicitly deallocate it with `delete` or `delete[]`.

As far as the *scope* is concerned: there's no such a thing as a scope for dynamically allocated memory. We usually talk about *scope* for automatic memory (because automatic memory will be deallocated at the end of the scope). The rules for the scope of the pointer to the dynamically allocated memory, on the other hand, are the same as any other automatic object.

In the C++ Standard (N3797 draft) this is specified at §3.7.4/1:

> Objects can be created dynamically during program execution (1.9), using *new-expressions* (5.3.4), and destroyed using *delete-expressions* (5.3.5). A C++ implementation provides access to, and management of, dynamic storage via the global allocation functions `operator new` and `operator new[]` and the global deallocation functions operator `delete` and `operator delete[]`.

Comment: Shoe@ What if the program is terminated? Will the be memory freed then or it will be remain allocated until the system is reboot?

Comment: @dlpcoder I believe that depends on the OS you are running on, but I would expect the OS to claim the memory back at the end of your program.

Answer (score 3):

Untill you destory the object exist it remains in memory, furthermore if you provide a pointer to that object (or more common use get/set functions) it can be accessed from outside the class.

Answer (score 2):

The `new` operator is same as `malloc()` in pure C. It's lifetime is until it gets freed as you would do with `delete`!

quote from C99 7.20.3 :

> The lifetime of an allocated object extends
> from the allocation until the deallocation.

In c++98 standard it is said this way:

> 3.7.3
>
> Dynamic storage duration [basic.stc.dynamic]
> 1 Objects can be created dynamically during program execution (1.9), using newexpressions
> (5.3.4), and
> destroyed using deleteexpressions
> (5.3.5).

**EDIT**

This would even mean, its lifetime could exceed even the program lifetime.
Common Operating systems release the memory for you if you didn't do so.

But the standards don't say that the implementation has to care about not freed memory after programm termination, doesn't matter there would be any sense for.

Comment: Assume that a passed a reference to a function "f(int** a)" then in function f I allocated memory to 'a' like this: "a=new int*[4]; a[i]=...;" ,and i exited function 'f' without deleting 'a' explicitly. Now the question is that what is the result of 'a[3]' out of function 'f' ? I tested this in VS2019, and the result was that 'a' doesn't point to the right place. Its values lost after exiting function. why? they should exist!! I saved memory locations into 'a' inside 'f'.